# Xcode 7.1 iOS 9.0 watchOS 2 app stops running after install

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, watchos-2

When I run my watch kit app (WatchOS 2) in Xcode 7, Swift,  it installs and then finishes (stops). No error messages, it just stops. I've uninstalled and re-install both the IOS app and the watch app. No luck.  Runs fine in the simulator. If I create a new empty project, same behavior. When I check the watch app on the watch, the new build is installed. It just doesn't run from Xcode so  I can't get my debug messages. I am using the scheme for the IOS app and the Watch App. Is there anything to look for in the scheme config? I have also recently updated my provisioning profile and development certificates.

I've tried looking at similar questions, but so far they have not helped.

[Xcode successfully builds my target, but does not run the product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244953/xcode-successfully-builds-my-target-but-does-not-run-the-product)

[Debug/Run in Xcode stopped working. Executable settings are wrong and can't be fixed too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851408/debug-run-in-xcode-stopped-working-executable-settings-are-wrong-and-cant-be-f?rq=1)

and similar to:

["This app contains an app extension with an illegal bundle identifier" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007290/this-app-contains-an-app-extension-with-an-illegal-bundle-identifier-issue)

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 7.1.1. It was released within the last day or so.

Comment: Thx but I updated and no change.

Comment: The UI runs on the main thread - there is no thing like stopping for an app unless u call exit() or the app crashes. What does the console say?

Comment: Nothing on the console.

Comment: I've tried Xcode 7.2 and had the same results. Still stuck.

Comment: Yeah! I got it working. Although I do need to give it an assist by tapping on the watch icon once it is running.  I shut down my MAC. Deleted the app from the watch and phone. Shut down the phone and watch. Restarting everything, and it worked. I had done all of this previously but not all at the same time. And it was the first time I also restarted my MAC.

Answer (score 1):

There's several people with this problem. I can't give you any tips for iOS 9.0 and XCode 7.1 (Besides, reseting everything and trying again). But, If you update to watchOS 2.1, iOS 9.2 and XCode 7.2, everything works.

Comment: Thanks. This problem ultimately went away but I'm not sure entirely why. I did all of the updates, deleted the app and restarted my computer and it started to work.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue and I'm running watchOS 2.1, iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7.2. I'm using Obj-C though unlike the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you more, this solved the issue to me, by the way, I have been using Obj-c all the time, and that's not an issue.

Comment: I had the problem again. I 1) deleted and re-installed watchOS app 2) deleted and re-installed phone app 3) retarted Xcode 4) re-started the computer. 5) restarted the watch. None of this helped. Finally, I restarted the phone and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

With device connected, shut downing my iPhone and watch and then restarting fixes the problem.